# Как сделать индикатор защиты листа

Tags: excel, vba

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Хочу сделать индикатор того, что лист защищен или не защищен, т.е. если я защищаю лист, то ячейка `A1` становится красной, если снимаю защиту, зеленой.

```
Private Sub Индикатор()
    If ActiveSheet.Protect Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End Sub
```

Мой код не работает... Подскажите, что не так.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Это дубликать вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/513785

Comment: Оттуда автора "попросили", чтобы создал вопрос отдельно, Вы отсюда гоните... Куда податься бедному вопрошающему? )

Answer (score 1):

В `VBA` есть понятие событий листа. Это действия, на которые может реагировать код в `VBA`. Защита листа или ее снятие не являются событиями, макрос не сможет отслеживать эти действия. Условное форматировани тоже не поймет их.

Можно проверять свойство листа `ProtectContents` (установлена ли защита):

```
If ProtectContents = True Then
    Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
    Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
```

Но такая проверка сама по себе не сработает, ее нужно подвешивать на событие лиcта, книги, на кнопку... Т.е. какая-то индикация сработает не при изменении защиты, а при другом действии. Например, защитили лист, после этого нажали кнопку.

Запускать проверку состояния защиты листа событиями... Можно, но нежелательно. Например, событием изменения на листе `Worksheet_Change`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
......
End Sub
```

При любом изменении будет срабатывать код проверки. 1000 раз за рабочий день что-то поменяли на листе - столько же раз макрос проверил состояние защиты.

О индикации заливкой. На защищенном листе можно менять заливку ячеек, если разрешено форматирование, т.е. при защите листа нужно устанавливать галку *Разрешить форматирование ячеек*. Забыли - получили ошибку при попытке поменять заливку.

Лучше вместо заливки менять значение ячейки. Она должна быть незащищенной (*Формат ячейки-Защита*, снять галку *Защищаемая ячейка*), а заливку сделать условным форматированием.

Но даже на защищенном листе сотрудник-шутник сможет изменить заливку на обратную )

Если уж очень надо получить такую индикацию и чтобы она была привязана непосредственно к действию *защита/снятие*, защищать лист можно макросом, подвешенным на кнопку на листе:

```
Sub СheckProtectSheet()
    Dim sTxt As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        If .ProtectContents = True Then
            sTxt = Application.InputBox("Впишите пароль для снятия защиты листа")
            
            On Error GoTo err_
            .Unprotect (sTxt)
            .Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
err_:
            If Err Then MsgBox "Неверный пароль", 64, "ОШИБКА"
        Else
            sTxt = Application.InputBox("Впишите пароль для защиты листа")
            
            If sTxt = Application.InputBox("Повторите пароль еще раз") Then
                .Range("AL1").Interior.Color = vbRed
                .Protect (sTxt)
            Else
                MsgBox "Второй пароль не совпал с первым", 64, "ОШИБКА"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Макрос разместить в общем модуле. Естественно, при ручном изменении защиты макрос не сработает

Comment: добрый вечер! большое спасибо за ответ